# Efficiently finding consecutive streaks in a pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame similar to the below:, and I want to add a Streak column to it  (see example below):

```
Date         Home_Team    Away_Team    Winner      Streak

2005-08-06       A            G           A           0
2005-08-06       B            H           H           0
2005-08-06       C            I           C           0
2005-08-06       D            J           J           0
2005-08-06       E            K           K           0
2005-08-06       F            L           F           0
2005-08-13       A            B           A           1           
2005-08-13       C            D           D           1           
2005-08-13       E            F           F           0        
2005-08-13       G            H           H           0
2005-08-13       I            J           J           0
2005-08-13       K            L           K           1
2005-08-20       B            C           B           0
2005-08-20       A            D           A           2
2005-08-20       G            K           K           0
2005-08-20       I            E           E           0
2005-08-20       F            H           F           2
2005-08-20       J            L           J           2
2005-08-27       A            H           A           3
2005-08-27       B            F           B           1
2005-08-27       J            C           C           3           
2005-08-27       D            E           D           0
2005-08-27       I            K           K           0
2005-08-27       L            G           G           0
2005-09-05       B            A           A           2
2005-09-05       D            C           D           1
2005-09-05       F            E           F           0
2005-09-05       H            G           H           0
2005-09-05       J            I           I           0
2005-09-05       K            L           K           4
```

The DataFrame is approximately 200k rows going from 2005 to 2020.

Now, what I am trying to do is find the number of consecutive games the Home Team has won PRIOR to the date in in the Date column in the DataFrame.
I have a solution, but it is too slow, see below:

```
df["Streak"] = 0
def home_streak(x): # x is a row of the DataFrame
    """Keep track of a team's winstreak"""
    home_team = x["Home_Team"]
    date = x["Date"]
    
    # all previous matches for the home team 
    home_df = df[(df["Home_Team"] == home_team) | (df["Away_Team"] == home_team)]
    home_df = home_df[home_df["Date"] <  date].sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).reset_index()
    if len(home_df.index) == 0: # no previous matches for that team, so start streak at 0
        return 0
    elif home_df.iloc[0]["Winner"] != home_team: # lost the last match
        return 0
    else: # they won the last game
        winners = home_df["Winner"]
        streak = 0
        for i in winners.index:
            if home_df.iloc[i]["Winner"] == home_team:
                streak += 1
            else: # they lost, return the streak
                return streak

df["Streak"] = df.apply(lambda x: home_streak(x), axis = 1)
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: So you want to group by home team and compute sequential wins?

Comment: What happens if `A` wins as an away team? What if it loses? Does that continue/end the streak? Or does the info get lost?

Comment: It continues/ends the streak. Home/Away does not matter with respect to the streak, I just want the streak for the home team that's all.

Comment: I see. So you are ok with seeing a jump? How will you know the length of the streak for teams that end as an away team? You can always add a column for away team streak...

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that, but to save some typing I just added the home team win streak as I can just apply the same method to the away team as I do to the home team

Comment: Makes sense. I just want to  make sure I fully understand the question before I answer. Last question: Are you OK with a numpy rather than a pandas solution?

Comment: hey correct your question it's confusing. This streak not home win streak

Comment: You need to provide better rather than more data. Please include all the possible corner cases we already discussed. A wins as home, A loses as home, A wins as away, A loses as away. Perhaps restrict the example to 3-4 teams so you don't need to provide so much superfluous data.

Comment: why is ```2005-08-13       C            D           D           1 ``` row with 1 here in the sample? There is no row where D hometeam has been a winner before and this row has C as hometeam while D as winner.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal good spot, that's a typo

Comment: @AkshaySehgal actually, it isn't. I'm interested in the streak of the home team, in this case it is C. C won its previous game (against I).

Comment: similarly, ```J            L           J           2```. This has a value of 2 but there is no row above it where J is a hometeam. is this a sample from a larger dataset?

Comment: oh ok, so J has won 2 times (as home or away doesnt matter )before this row, so where-ever it is a home team, it should reflect its streak. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. J has won its previous 2 matches hence its streak is 2.

Comment: @theman - Why is ```2005-09-05       K            L           K           1``` the last row =1?

Comment: Sorry, that is a genuine typo

Comment: Also, ```2005-09-05       H            G           H           0``` Third last row, has 0 while H has won before 2 times

Comment: check my solution and let me know 1. if my output is right, 2. if my solutions isnt the simplest of the lot :)

Comment: No, H lost its last game against A

Comment: Ahh ok, let me fix that. should be fixable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will present a numpy-based solution here. Firstly because I am not very familiar with pandas and don't feel like doing the research, and secondly because a numpy solution should work just fine regardless.

Let's take a look at what happens to one given team first. Your goal is to find the number of consecutive wins for a team based on the sequence of games it participated in. I will drop the date column and turn your data into a numpy array for starters:

```
x = np.array([
    ['A', 'G', 'A'],
    ['B', 'H', 'H'],
    ['C', 'I', 'C'],
    ['D', 'J', 'J'],
    ['E', 'K', 'K'],
    ['F', 'L', 'F'],
    ['A', 'B', 'A'],
    ['C', 'D', 'D'],
    ['E', 'F', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'H'],
    ['I', 'J', 'J'],
    ['K', 'L', 'K'],
    ['B', 'C', 'B'],
    ['A', 'D', 'A'],
    ['G', 'K', 'K'],
    ['I', 'E', 'E'],
    ['F', 'H', 'F'],
    ['J', 'L', 'J']])
```

You don't need the date because all you care about is who played, even if they did it multiple times in one day. So let's take a look at just team `A`:

```
A_played = np.flatnonzero((x[:, :2] == 'A').any(axis=1))
A_won = x[A_played, -1] == 'A'
```

`A_played` is an index array with the same number of elements as there are rows in `x`. `A_won` is a mask that has as many elements as `np.count_nonzero(A_played)`; i.e., the number of games `A` participated in.

Finding the sizes of the streaks is a fairly well hashed out problem:

```
streaks = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[False, A_won, False])))[::2]
```

You compute the differences between each pair of indices where the value of the mask switches. The extra padding with `False` ensures that you know which way the mask is switching. What you are looking for is based on this computation but requires a bit more detail, since you want the cumulative sum, but reset after each run. You can do that by setting the value of the data to the negated run length immediately after the run:

```
wins = np.r_[0, A_won, 0]  # Notice the int dtype here
switch_indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(wins)) + 1
streaks = np.diff(switch_indices)[::2]
wins[switch_indices[1::2]] = -streaks
```

Now you have a trimmable array whose cumulative sum can be assigned directly to the output columns:

```
streak_counts = np.cumsum(wins[:-2])
output = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 2), dtype=int)

# Home streak
home_mask = x[A_played, 0] == 'A'
output[A_played[home_mask], 0] = streak_counts[home_mask]

# Away streak
away_mask = ~home_mask
output[A_played[away_mask], 1] = streak_counts[away_mask]
```

Now you can loop over all teams (which should be a fairly small number compared to the total number of games):

```
def process_team(data, team, output):
    played = np.flatnonzero((data[:, :2] == team).any(axis=1))
    won = data[played, -1] == team
    wins = np.r_[0, won, 0]
    switch_indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(wins)) + 1
    streaks = np.diff(switch_indices)[::2]
    wins[switch_indices[1::2]] = -streaks
    streak_counts = np.cumsum(wins[:-2])

    home_mask = data[played, 0] == team
    away_mask = ~home_mask

    output[played[home_mask], 0] = streak_counts[home_mask]
    output[played[away_mask], 1] = streak_counts[away_mask]

output = np.empty((x.shape[0], 2), dtype=int)

# Assume every team has been home team at least once.
# If not, x[:, :2].ravel() copies the data and np.unique(x[:, :2]) does too
for team in set(x[:, 0]):
    process_team(x, team, output)
```

Comment: This solution appears to be nearly correct, but I think it's missing the fact that I want to look at the streak of games won PRIOR to the game being played, this solution appears to add ```1``` to the streak on the same row as the game ( if they win), when it should be added to the streak in the row for the next game

Comment: So the first time a team plays, the streak should be initialised at ```0```, and from there on, the streak depends on the previous games (all games played before the current game we are considering).

Comment: @theman thanks for the catch. I've adjusted the contract appropriately. I know that your data doesn't have this scenario, but this solution works regardless of how many games a team plays per day since we drop the time index.

Comment: This doesn't quite work either. It seems as though a team has to win at least twice in a row for it to show up in the streak. Also, when a team loses, the streak seems to be set to zero on that row and not the next match

Comment: @theman. That's what happens when I'm on mobile :) I'll fix when I can test on a desktop

Comment: @theman. So just to be clear, streaks have a lag of one: first win: streak is zero. second win streak is 1, third game is loss, but streak is 2 because 2 prior wins? Only then does the streak reset to zero until *after* the next win?

Comment: @theman. I've updated the solution. Let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose this over the pandas solution?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Your solution is the only one that works, the other two answers don't work. My pandas solution is far too slow, this is much more efficient

Answer (score 3):

Elegant way:

```
new_df = (df.reset_index()
            .melt(['index', 'Date', 'Winner'])
            .assign(win=lambda x: x['value'].eq(x.Winner))
            .sort_values('Date')
            .assign(cum_wins=lambda x: x.groupby('value')['win'].cumsum())
            .assign(cum_wins_prev=lambda x: x.groupby('value')['cum_wins'].shift(fill_value=0))
            .pivot_table(index='index', values='cum_wins_prev', columns='variable')
            .add_prefix('Streak_')
         )
print(new_df)
```

---

```
variable  Streak_Away_Team  Streak_Home_Team
index                                       
0                      0.0               0.0
1                      0.0               0.0
2                      0.0               0.0
3                      0.0               0.0
4                      0.0               0.0
5                      0.0               0.0
6                      0.0               1.0
7                      0.0               1.0
8                      1.0               0.0
9                      1.0               0.0
10                     1.0               0.0
11                     0.0               1.0
12                     1.0               0.0
13                     1.0               2.0
14                     2.0               0.0
15                     0.0               0.0
16                     2.0               2.0
17                     0.0               2.0
```

---

```
#new_df = df.assign(**new_df) #you could use join or assign 
new_df = df.join(new_df) 
print(new_df)



          Date Home_Team Away_Team Winner  Streak_Away_Team  Streak_Home_Team
0   2005-08-06         A         G      A               0.0               0.0
1   2005-08-06         B         H      H               0.0               0.0
2   2005-08-06         C         I      C               0.0               0.0
3   2005-08-06         D         J      J               0.0               0.0
4   2005-08-06         E         K      K               0.0               0.0
5   2005-08-06         F         L      F               0.0               0.0
6   2005-08-13         A         B      A               0.0               1.0
7   2005-08-13         C         D      D               0.0               1.0
8   2005-08-13         E         F      F               1.0               0.0
9   2005-08-13         G         H      H               1.0               0.0
10  2005-08-13         I         J      J               1.0               0.0
11  2005-08-13         K         L      K               0.0               1.0
12  2005-08-20         B         C      B               1.0               0.0
13  2005-08-20         A         D      A               1.0               2.0
14  2005-08-20         G         K      K               2.0               0.0
15  2005-08-20         I         E      E               0.0               0.0
16  2005-08-20         F         H      F               2.0               2.0
17  2005-08-20         J         L      J               0.0               2.0
```

it is understood that a team does not play more than once a day

**Times**

```
%%timeit
df["Streak"] = 0
def home_streak(x): # x is a row of the DataFrame
    """Keep track of a team's winstreak"""
    home_team = x["Home_Team"]
    date = x["Date"]
    
    # all previous matches for the home team 
    home_df = df[(df["Home_Team"] == home_team) | (df["Away_Team"] == home_team)]
    home_df = home_df[home_df["Date"] <  date].sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).reset_index()
    if len(home_df.index) == 0: # no previous matches for that team, so start streak at 0
        return 0
    elif home_df.iloc[0]["Winner"] != home_team: # lost the last match
        return 0
    else: # they won the last game
        winners = home_df["Winner"]
        streak = 0
        for i in winners.index:
            if home_df.iloc[i]["Winner"] == home_team:
                streak += 1
            else: # they lost, return the streak
                return streak

df["Streak"] = df.apply(lambda x: home_streak(x), axis = 1)

66.2 ms ± 9.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit

new_df = (df.reset_index()
            .melt(['index', 'Date', 'Winner'])
            .assign(win=lambda x: x['value'].eq(x.Winner))
            .sort_values('Date')
            .assign(cum_wins=lambda x: x.groupby('value')['win'].cumsum())
            .assign(cum_wins_prev=lambda x: x.groupby('value')['cum_wins'].shift(fill_value=0))
            .pivot_table(index='index', values='cum_wins_prev', columns='variable')
            .add_prefix('Streak_')
         )
new_df=df.assign(**new_df)

29.5 ms ± 2.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either; I'm getting wild values for the streaks (100+) which I know not to be true.

Comment: Could one team play more than one time in a day?

Comment: No, once per day maximum

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a `pandas` solution, but you can assign a group number using `ngroup` and then use `defaultdict` to create groups so you can lookup the accumulate results:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

df["group"] = df.groupby("Date").ngroup()

for a, b in zip(df["Winner"], df["group"]):
    d[b][a] = 1+d.get(b-1,{}).get(a, 0)

df["Streak"] = [d.get(y-1, {}).get(x, 0) for x, y in zip(df["Home_Team"], df["group"])]

print (df.drop("group", 1))

          Date Home_Team Away_Team Winner  Streak
0   2005-08-06         A         G      A       0
1   2005-08-06         B         H      H       0
2   2005-08-06         C         I      C       0
3   2005-08-06         D         J      J       0
4   2005-08-06         E         K      K       0
5   2005-08-06         F         L      F       0
6   2005-08-13         A         B      A       1
7   2005-08-13         C         D      D       1
8   2005-08-13         E         F      F       0
9   2005-08-13         G         H      H       0
10  2005-08-13         I         J      J       0
11  2005-08-13         K         L      K       1
12  2005-08-20         B         C      B       0
13  2005-08-20         A         D      A       2
14  2005-08-20         G         K      K       0
15  2005-08-20         I         E      E       0
16  2005-08-20         F         H      F       2
17  2005-08-20         J         L      J       2
18  2005-08-27         A         H      A       3
19  2005-08-27         B         F      B       1
20  2005-08-27         J         C      C       3
21  2005-08-27         D         E      D       0
22  2005-08-27         I         K      K       0
23  2005-08-27         L         G      G       0
24  2005-09-05         B         A      A       2
25  2005-09-05         D         C      D       1
26  2005-09-05         F         E      F       0
27  2005-09-05         H         G      H       0
28  2005-09-05         J         I      I       0
29  2005-09-05         K         L      K       4
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The only values I'm getting in the Streak column are 0, 1 and 2, and in my larger DataFrame I know there are streaks much longer than 2

Comment: I've added more data now

Comment: It worked just fine. Your problem lies somewhere else, probably inconsistent data.

Comment: Hmm, does the fact that sometimes there are ties mess with your solution? As in, in the ```Winner``` column, occasionally there is: ```"tie"```. I've only just noticed this now, apologies.

Comment: It shouldn't change anything. There will be a new group called "tie" but it doesn't affect the others. Are you sure the names of the teams stayed the same throughout your data, without typo?

Comment: Yes, they're consistent as this would also mess my solution up (which works fine).

Comment: Ok, no worries, I can wait. Thanks for your help

Comment: Solution 1 does not work for me; there seems to be no discernible pattern to the streak so I'm not sure what's going on. It definitely does not reset to zero after a draw/loss.

Comment: Solution 2 is throwing an error;   ```"None of ['group'] are in the columns"```

Comment: Also, in your output, this is not correct, it does not match mine. For example, team J lost to team C on ```2005-08-27```but on the next gameweek ```2005-09-05 ``` you have team J at a streak of 3 when it should be zero.

Comment: Then the original solution should have been correct. What was wrong in the solution prior to these revise?

Comment: The values in the streaks columns were only ```0, 1 or 2```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the logic is correct and it works for the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXES IN PROGRESS!**

Here is probably the simplest approach -

```
def get_streak(l,m,n):
    wins = np.roll(np.cumsum([1 if i==n else 0 for i in l]),1)
    wins[0]=0
    filts = np.array([1 if i==n else 0 for i in m])
    mul = np.multiply(wins, filts)
    return mul


streaks = np.zeros((30,)).astype(int)
l = list(df['Winner'])
m = list(df['Home_Team'])

for i in df['Winner'].unique():
    streaks += get_streak(l,m,i)
    
df['streaks'] = streaks
```

```
          Date Home_Team Away_Team Winner  streaks
0   2005-08-06         A         G      A        0
1   2005-08-06         B         H      H        0
2   2005-08-06         C         I      C        0
3   2005-08-06         D         J      J        0
4   2005-08-06         E         K      K        0
5   2005-08-06         F         L      F        0
6   2005-08-13         A         B      A        1
7   2005-08-13         C         D      D        1
8   2005-08-13         E         F      F        0
9   2005-08-13         G         H      H        0
10  2005-08-13         I         J      J        0
11  2005-08-13         K         L      K        1
12  2005-08-20         B         C      B        0
13  2005-08-20         A         D      A        2
14  2005-08-20         G         K      K        0
15  2005-08-20         I         E      E        0
16  2005-08-20         F         H      F        2
17  2005-08-20         J         L      J        2
18  2005-08-27         A         H      A        3
19  2005-08-27         B         F      B        1
20  2005-08-27         J         C      C        3
21  2005-08-27         D         E      D        1
22  2005-08-27         I         K      K        0
23  2005-08-27         L         G      G        0
24  2005-09-05         B         A      A        2
25  2005-09-05         D         C      D        2
26  2005-09-05         F         E      F        3
27  2005-09-05         H         G      H        2
28  2005-09-05         J         I      I        3
29  2005-09-05         K         L      K        4
```

It's pretty straightforward -

1. You take a cumulative sum of the wins of a given team and shift them by 1.
2. Then you take the dot product of those with the instances where they were the home team. Save that to a vector called streak
3. You loop through all the unique home teams and calculate the sum of their streaks.
4. Done!

A more intuitive sense of how the function works can be seen with some print statements -

```
def get_streak(l,m,n):
    wins = np.roll(np.cumsum([1 if i==n else 0 for i in l]),1)
    wins[0]=0
    print('wins:',wins)
    filts = np.array([1 if i==n else 0 for i in m])
    print('home:',filts)
    mul = np.multiply(wins, filts)
    print('strk:', mul)
    return mul

streak_A = get_streak(l,m,'A')
```

```
wins: [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5]
home: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
strk: [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

The element-wise sum of all the streaks is what you are looking for.

---

Benchmark (seems to be the fastest among all other answers) -

529 µs ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

use pandas and duckdb

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=df1.sql().filter("date<='{}'".format(dd.Date.iloc[0])).select("*,case when date='{}' then Home_Team else Winner end as winner2".format(dd.Date.iloc[0])).order("date desc").df()
    dd2=dd1.groupby(['winner2'],as_index=False).agg(col2=("col1",lambda x:x.diff(-1).eq(1).cumprod().sum()))
    return dd.sql().join(dd2.sql().select("winner2,col2"),"home_team=winner2",'left').select("* exclude(index,winner2)").df()

df1.assign(col1=df1.Date.rank(method='dense')).groupby(['Date'],as_index=False).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=1).fillna(0)

：

          Date Home_Team Away_Team Winner  col2
0   2005-08-06         A         G      A       0
1   2005-08-06         B         H      H       0
2   2005-08-06         C         I      C       0
3   2005-08-06         D         J      J       0
4   2005-08-06         E         K      K       0
5   2005-08-06         F         L      F       0
6   2005-08-13         A         B      A       1
7   2005-08-13         C         D      D       1
8   2005-08-13         E         F      F       0
9   2005-08-13         G         H      H       0
10  2005-08-13         I         J      J       0
11  2005-08-13         K         L      K       1
12  2005-08-20         B         C      B       0
13  2005-08-20         A         D      A       2
14  2005-08-20         G         K      K       0
15  2005-08-20         I         E      E       0
16  2005-08-20         F         H      F       2
17  2005-08-20         J         L      J       2
18  2005-08-27         A         H      A       3
19  2005-08-27         B         F      B       1
20  2005-08-27         J         C      C       3
21  2005-08-27         D         E      D       0
22  2005-08-27         I         K      K       0
23  2005-08-27         L         G      G       0
24  2005-09-05         B         A      A       2
25  2005-09-05         D         C      D       1
26  2005-09-05         F         E      F       0
27  2005-09-05         H         G      H       0
28  2005-09-05         J         I      I       0
29  2005-09-05         K         L      K       4
```